# Copy data with filter applied using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy, paste

I noticed that using Range.Copy and Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy give the same result, and I don't quite understand why, what is actually the difference of the two?

As an simple example:
If I have spreadsheet like the following (from A1:C6)

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

If I filter out 3, then the visible data becomes:

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

When I was trying to copy the above data with filter applied to another range, I tested the following two methods had the same results, which only copied the data with "3" filtered out, but why?
Method 1:

```
Range("A1:C6").Copy
Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Method 2:

```
Range("A1:C6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Intuitively, comparing these two, only the second should exclude the invisible filtered out data, but the first one seems should have included all the data, including the invisible ones.
Now that they result says they are the same, and if they are, then what would the difference be?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

try to copy range manually - you will get only filtered cells
from VBA code Excel behave the same way as you did manually
if you want to get complete cells block, the simplest way - to deactivate filter
if this way unacceptable, you can copy value every cell value in cycle, but it is unefficient way
Set rng=Range("A1:C6")
for each cell from rng do
...
next cell

Comment: This answer is not so clear. Try to format it better, and use the code tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim v As Variant, r As Range, dest As Range
   Set r = Me.Range("A1:C6")  'filtered range to copy
   v = r
   Set dest = Me.Range("D10").Resize(r.Rows.CountLarge, r.Columns.CountLarge)
   dest = v
End Sub
```

[image: the result of pressing the button]

the result of pressing the button